# Python duplicated empty list problem with append

Tags: python, list, append, empty-list

The following code surprised me.

```
alist = [[]] * 4

alist[0].append(100)
```

I expected that alist would be

```
[[100],[],[],[]]
```

but it turned out to be

```
[[100],[100],[100],[100]]
```

Does anyone know why python works that way? thank you.

Comment: That's the difference of value and reference.list is same as reference.

Comment: You could check that is the same reference with help of `is` such that `alist[0] is alist[1]` is True but in other case `alist = [[] for _ in range(4)]` all references will be points to a 4 different empty list objects. Also check that `alist[0] is []` is False.

Answer (score 1):

on this line `alist = [[]] * 4` you are creating one inner list and 4 references to the same list, to fix this you can use:

```
alist = [[] for _ in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alist1 = [[] for _ in range(4)]
alist1[0] = 100
print(alist1)
```

Comment: After the first line you can just `alist1[0] = 100`. No need for the second loop

Comment: it is not a repetition of my answer? but I also gave explanations